# glib i18n on Windows

Tags: c++, internationalization, gtk, gettext, glib

I am trying to run C++ GTK2 application on Windows 7, using Eclipse CDT + MinGW and GTK 2.22. It uses `<glib/gi18n.h>` for internationalization and it works perfectly on Linux. However, I can't make it work on Windows. I initialize localization using this code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "sk_SK");
bindtextdomain ("MyApp", "MyPath");
bind_textdomain_codeset ("MyApp", "UTF-8");
textdomain ("MyApp");
```

None of these functions returns `NULL`, so they finish successfully.

Then when I try to obtain a string using:

```
gettext("someText");
```

, I get only "someText", which means that my translations file was not found.

My GNU-gettext created language file is MyPath/sk_SK/LC_MESSAGES/MyApp.mo.
The only way I can make this work is to set the `LC_ALL` environment variable in Windows manually to `sk_SK` (but `putenv("LC_ALL=sk_SK")` in my code does not work either).